# Match beginning of a line with something there?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, perl

I want to match the beginning of lines where the line contains something.

Command in Perl/Sed

```
's/^.?/\section{}/g'
```

but the problem here is that it replaces also the first character of sentences.

How can you add to the beginning of lines something for non-empty lines?

Comment: I think what you want is not clear. Do you want to add something to the beginning of some lines ?

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/./s/^/\\section{}/'
```

Would prepend `\section{}` to every line that contain at least one *valid* character.

```
sed '/^$/!s/^/\\section{}/'
```

Would prepend `\section{}` to every non-empty line (that is lines that contain at least one *byte*).

```
sed 's/./\\section{}&/'
```

Would insert `\section{}` before the first valid character in every line (that has such a valid character). (`&` is replaced by the matched portion).

Those distinctions between *byte* and *character* can be meaningfull if you're in a multi-byte-per-character locale (like UTF-8 which tends to be the norm nowadays) but dealing with text encoded in an extended single-byte character set.

For instance:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ echo Москва | iconv -t iso-8859-5 | sed 's/./\\section{}&/' | iconv -f iso-8859-5
Москва
```

(when encoded in iso-8859-5, none of the resuling byte values for Москва form a valid character in UTF-8, so `/./` doesn't match anything).

Since in your case, encoding would not be a concern since the text you're inserted is ASCII anyway, you can fix the locale to C to avoid surprises:

```
$ echo Москва | iconv -t iso-8859-5 | LC_ALL=C sed 's/./\\section{}&/' | iconv -f iso-8859-5
\section{}Москва
```

Comment: What can happen if you do not do this `LC_ALL=C`? I have seen sometimes symbols like <CR> ... in my text-editors in working between terminal and text-editor. Can this help for stopping this from happening?

Comment: @Masi, see the edit for an example of a problem addressed by LC_ALL=C.  `CR` are another kind of problem not related with locales. `CR` is a character in all locales. It is not the line delimiter character on Unix, so would be part of the content of the line and then matched by `.`. It is generally considered a _vertical spacing_ character. You could replace your `/./` with `/[^[:space:]]/` to match on lines that contain at least one non-spacing character.

Comment: How can you confirm this locale setting `LC_ALL=C`, for instance in Perl?

Comment: @Masi, `perl` ignores the locale unless you use things like `-CL` or `-Mopen=locale` or `-Mlocale`... or the equivalent `use` statements. See `perldoc perllocale` for details.

Comment: So no locale need to be set then with strict and warnings in Perl. I am converting my one-liners to Perl with strict and warning packages. Is this a good solution to avoid the problem with locale?

Comment: Trying to read manual but getting this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30942725/54964

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in two statements with `sed` : the first one to ensure no empty lines are matched, the second to append at the beginning :

```
sed '/^$/n;s/^/\\section{}/'
```

Or you could do it in one statement by capturing what you match and adding it to your replacement :

```
sed 's/^\(.\)/\\section{}\1/'
```

Here, the parentheses `\(` and `\)` define a capturing group referenced by the `\1` in the replacement part of the statement.

Also note that, in order to make sure the line isn't empty, you need to remove the interrogation mark `?` after the dot `.`. `?` means "0 or 1", so the empty line would match the 0-length.

Comment: I like the first one which I also think is more efficient, since no regex there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a zero-width positive look-ahead assertion:

```
perl -pe 's/^(?=.)/\section{}/'
```

[`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) says:

> `(?=pattern)` A zero-width positive look-ahead assertion. For example, `/\w+(?=\t)/` matches a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in `$&`

Another solution:

```
perl -lpe 's/^/\section{}/ if length'
```

You should chomp `\n` at the end of a line before length checking.

The `-l` option do it for you.

> `-l[octnum]` enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps `$/` (the input record separator) when used with `-n` or `-p`. Second, it assigns `$\` (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets `$\` to the current value of `$/`